# What is the equivalent method to onResume() in Ionic 2?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

Whereas in Android Native there is the `onResume()` that is part of the [life cycle of an activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). Look this:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first    
}
```

What is the equivalent method to `onResume()` in Ionic 2?

Comment: Check this link : https://www.google.co.in/amp/blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/amp/?client=safari

Comment: If your issue is resolved..then plz accept the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Platform.resume` of ionic 2 as explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/)